# Model Building (Random forest) for accelerometer data

Tags: r, random-forest

I am developing a model using R-studio for predicting behaviour in dogs using a tri-axial accelerometer which produces X, Y and Z values.
I am using a random forest model and I am looking for a code that allows the model to identify two behaviours (such as barking and standing) occurring at the same time, however they do not always occur at the same time. Currently, my model only only accepts the detection of one behaviour at a time. Any help would be appreciated. The annotated data that was collected by watching video recordings recorded two behaviours occurring simultaneously (e.g. standing AND sniffing), however, my current model is not picking this up when merged with my accelerometer data.

Here is an example of data for my question that I got from the dput function.

```
structure(list(Behavior = c("Barking", "Barking", "Barking", 
"Barking", "Barking", "Defecating", "Defecating", "Defecating", 
"Defecating", "Defecating", "Drinking", "Drinking", "Drinking", 
"Drinking", "Drinking", "Eating", "Eating", "Eating", "Eating", 
"Eating", "Jumping", "Jumping", "Jumping", "Jumping", "Jumping", 
"Lateral-Recumbency", "Lateral-Recumbency", "Lateral-Recumbency", 
"Lateral-Recumbency", "Lateral-Recumbency", "Lying Head Down", 
"Lying Head Down", "Lying Head Down", "Lying Head Down", "Lying Head Down", 
"Lying Head Up", "Lying Head Up", "Lying Head Up", "Lying Head Up", 
"Lying Head Up", "Running", "Running", "Running", "Running", 
"Running", "Scratching", "Scratching", "Scratching", "Scratching", 
"Scratching", "Sitting", "Sitting", "Sitting", "Sitting", "Sitting", 
"Sniffing", "Sniffing", "Sniffing", "Sniffing", "Sniffing", "Standing", 
"Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Standing", "Trotting", "Trotting", 
"Trotting", "Trotting", "Trotting", "Urinating", "Urinating", 
"Urinating", "Urinating", "Urinating", "Walking", "Walking", 
"Walking", "Walking", "Walking"), X_Mean = c(-0.699228106144098, 
0.996451529666396, -0.69274535356833, -0.103483046838697, 0.603866064318714, 
-0.608044983359464, 0.0848661205199916, 1.57799019874749, -0.463653743705612, 
-1.15852700589699, 0.723685640977932, -0.784540661183284, -0.268400025520266, 
0.507799265824037, 0.461331003901638, 1.17944958556405, -0.67939633341417, 
-0.318611569966249, -0.658019293864502, -0.162615980275628, 1.98934911973313, 
-0.0610519410969586, -0.0278099839182587, 0.511525893301122, 
-1.21675338327355, 0.953601027080163, -0.0583640451901847, -0.704946172078452, 
0.37431582186532, -0.183167317158162, -0.151614769827921, -0.114874638716652, 
1.54720521421964, -0.552909864931753, 0.954259677245468, 0.164420107478753, 
-0.277725410828986, -0.644419619223862, -0.367106009737265, -0.275913323896434, 
1.0906215035097, -0.781372921136103, 1.64332373376438, -0.170785226051006, 
-0.653641910106926, -0.707909530538924, 0.188105486356753, 1.74803479722261, 
-0.224260839154788, -0.095715548183244, 0.205072404879131, 0.0634116980727395, 
-0.741664430606325, 0.988291199131346, -1.23052423256499, -0.980080361865213, 
-0.415431332879817, -0.27844094049977, 1.05409934754309, -0.62305895188382, 
-0.178191822257626, -0.332385705278369, 1.60388383078126, 1.44882146078712, 
-1.05839965003638, 0.436514338345504, -1.29720147388242, -0.829073430273456, 
-0.581611242371406, -0.847301808931937, 0.228593291980103, -0.313185666444505, 
0.306202128122618, 1.22963755720089, 1.17110292471268, -2.0712886450964, 
-0.254411710301793, 0.476396540102075, 1.1648359123802, -0.570515444184433
), Y_Mean = c(0.127827928639979, 1.63205862988908, 0.198993869675984, 
1.87590306780823, -2.21675513493914, 2.03387780206071, -2.37498614160957, 
1.13308270961088, 1.06322316087704, -0.379907282555215, -0.331000594076846, 
0.355548081917882, 0.169888599035472, 0.239238593824761, 1.31400656157686, 
0.229274976791376, -2.0642553710307, 0.41627418952243, -0.32273060276783, 
0.842913529277499, -0.874938548515266, -0.250570213789226, -1.53788372174715, 
-1.48353381221735, -1.7447381269927, 0.0242356783728676, -2.74161388015182, 
1.25450869273938, -0.650621197553096, 0.0146697562119895, 1.19810154911883, 
0.30121905668371, 0.421688779118986, -0.636610202834169, -1.29425839270764, 
0.641573251982327, -0.20300577965444, -3.84840269995274e-05, 
-0.824594641794736, -0.556709400434332, -2.29142750276276, -1.65236977680908, 
-1.57125070163983, -0.180305124601422, -1.06639966452267, 0.389090532297012, 
0.0352335986748661, -0.498454515445811, -1.6054317144697, -0.67093240335342, 
0.892725899985323, 0.476799443153048, -0.311867437303258, -2.24435886762858, 
-0.486200731941719, -2.92429113218381, 1.77384268160864, 0.0337124389773445, 
1.26106595229873, -0.173960891087615, 2.07554917645169, -0.898641835997367, 
0.837990321501561, -0.0109436319889317, 0.727129908185823, -1.32523126613269, 
2.23816322683861, 0.302436273877211, -0.496712975638095, -1.18622500956318, 
-1.52534163542218, -1.8163370958066, -1.71753992490193, 0.039712049725824, 
1.12155646937291, 0.353915660950126, -1.93209497227857, 0.0857532249551007, 
1.50006794941982, 1.01468792813211), Z_Mean = c(1.84390932942692, 
0.41958246226038, -3.28937584855757, 0.642383067114167, 0.213093639533192, 
-1.7182887639908, -0.131452234665525, -0.671879471327625, -0.443464894242919, 
0.471270768091317, -0.59186388659965, -0.651915887319594, -1.45676385275197, 
0.172284600439745, 0.550965515977292, 0.571722040589605, 1.18917934773041, 
-2.36533381504662, 0.0332240411790732, -1.33429768089279, 0.608785792743954, 
0.0800248847271412, -1.06872802248799, -0.377553664195196, 1.40288067524327, 
-0.541441946412946, -1.72492124772187, 1.08919483753396, 1.16976360508389, 
-0.607156730101415, 1.65412285522879, -0.166080566390793, -1.27401899139188, 
-0.306040857753799, 0.254340425178138, 0.562471102501748, 0.385138526730681, 
1.23617915452482, 0.230932004729973, 0.516775157949177, 1.0255791375194, 
-0.166313578850091, -0.791567079440403, -0.282152279625528, -1.33336590569982, 
0.0496970129853213, 0.503797531825137, -1.04712783477107, -0.869470504201632, 
-1.10841870084243, -0.0404459582548468, 1.41657477550723, -0.632693871451233, 
-0.628558194189149, -0.025326160634408, -0.975476335713031, 1.01497226020659, 
-0.301907306658092, 1.1310543674245, 0.639451578125384, 0.794958784716343, 
-1.47913745549668, -1.68068071887634, 0.0589754749151921, -0.358304019532621, 
-0.339249854254092, -0.102197913003283, 1.60058413931273, -0.461803035391538, 
-0.617623540241725, 1.62733903509555, 0.223655476773407, 0.242420207917438, 
-1.29503270099671, 0.749241651724491, 1.1686553865313, 0.71429342693586, 
-1.14956738950403, 1.45037475149102, -0.297783274696659)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-80L))
```

**My code:**

```
#Load Libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(qwraps2)
library(caret)
library(randomForest)
library(mlbench)
library(psych)
library(data.table)
library(plot3D)

#Building Model

index.C<-createDataPartition(dfCompl$Behaviour,p=0.70,list=FALSE)
dftrain<-dfCompl[index.C,]
dftest<-dfCompl[-index.C,]

model.normal<-train(Behaviour~X_Mean+Y_Mean+Z_Mean+ODBA,data=dftrain,method="rf",trControl=trainControl(method="none"))
preds<-predict(model.normal,dftest)

#Confusion matrix
confusionMatrix(preds,as.factor(dftest$Behaviour))
table(preds)
```

I have tried to separate the behaviours that come with another behaviour such as barking and sniffing behaviours into their own models, but this hasn't produced high accuracy rates as there is still differences in stances with each of these behaviours.

Comment: Hi Cushla, welcome to SO. It will make it much easier to answer your question if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121). So run `dput()` on the data you are using e.g. `dput(df)` and copy the result into your question.. If your dataset is large, you can create some 'fake' data that is representative enough to reproduce your issue. Also, I think you may have forgotten to add your code to your question. Thanks

Comment: I have added those now. Let me know if that is suitable. Thankyou!

Comment: Awesome job. Answering this question is above my pay grade so I can't say for sure, but it appears you have provided enough information. If not, someone wiser than me will help guide you. Good luck!